# Copy a variable range from other files to a summary sheet

Tags: vba

This code is to open files and go to a certain sheet, grab everything from A11 to AC(down), go back to a report and progressively paste it one after the other, which works with the exception that it can't find the next available row so it pastes the new data over the previous data. I am quite sure that my efforts with LastRowSrce and LastRowDest is the culprit but I can't get it right. I saw some posts with UsedRange so I tried that but couldn't get it right either.
Any help greatly appreciated.

```
Sub CSReport()

Dim y As Long
Dim Wkb As Workbook
Dim Wks As Worksheet
Dim SFile As String              'srce file
Dim GWB As String                'dest file
Dim R1 As Range
Dim R2 As Range
Dim LastRowSrce As Long     'find last row in srce file
Dim LastRowDest As Long     'find last row in dest file

Set Wkb = thisWorkBook
Set Wks = Wkb.Worksheets("CS Report")

 Wks.Range("A11:AD10000").ClearContents

     Wks.Range("A4").value = "Status at  " & Time & "  " & Format(Date, "Long date")

    y = 11                                                      'start row
    SFile = Wkb.Path & "\"

    GWB = Dir(SFile & "*Audit*")
        Do While Len(GWB) > 0
            workbooks.Open fileName:=SFile & GWB

            LastRowSrce = workbooks(GWB).Worksheets("Audit Plan").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            LastRowDest = Wks.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

                Set R1 = workbooks(GWB).Worksheets("Audit Plan").Range("A" & y & ":AB" & LastRowSrce)
                Set R2 = Wks.Range("A" & y & ":AB" & LastRowSrce)

                R2.value = R1.value
                workbooks(GWB).Close False

                y = y + 1
            GWB = Dir
        Loop

       Wkb.Save

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Set R2 = Wks.Range("A" & y & ":AB" & LastRowSrce)
```

you keep setting the same range on the destination sheet... you need it to be dynamic.

```
set R2 = Wks.Range("A" & LastRowDest & ":AB" & LastRowDest+LastRowSrce-11)
```

try that...

Comment: So close... a lot more action on the sheet. First range comes across ok but it cuts the top row of each subsequent range. When I slowly F8 through the R1 & R2 ranges it all makes sense but the top row fails to come across. Any ideas?